# Geofence report using MongoDB - 'the right way'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I have a collection of millions of GPS events and a collection of a few user defined geofences.
The geofences are geoJSON polygons.

My mission is to allow my users to select a geofence, a time range, and then generate a report that shows when their vehicle entered the geofence, and then when it left.

The first approach I've taken is quite simple and doesn't take advantage of any of the geospatial features of MongoDB:

1. Execute a query to get a list of all the GPS events for the time range.
2. Stream (using mongoose QueryStream) the results and take note of the first GPS event that enters the geofence, and then take note of the next GPS event that exits. Push these 2 events into an array. A simple point-in-polygon function is used to determine if the GPS event is within or outside the geofence.
3. The output looks like: [{start: start_event, finish: finish_event}, {start: start_event, finish: finish_event}]

Of course this is probably the most inefficient way to do this, and sure enough, if I increase the date range beyond a couple of days, the time it takes becomes too long.

There are 2 other approaches I'm thinking about:

1. Rather than piping all events through the above process, limit the list of GPS events to those that are near the geofence first. For example, if I can work out the bounding box of the of the geofence polygon, I can figure out a maxDistance for a $geoNear query. This should significantly reduce the number of events that need to be processed using the same approach as above.
2. Use a $geoWithin query to select only the events that are within the geofence. The problem with this is it makes it more difficult to determine when the vehicle entered or exited. I'd have to rely on some time threshold to determine the sessions when the vehicle was inside the geofence.

At this stage, I'm leaning towards approach #1, but I'd really like to hear how other people would go about solving this problem using MongoDB - in particular using aggregation pipeline or  mapreduce.

Comment: I can't help with experience of your two nominated approaches, but I have a question for you.  Have you found (or coded) a geofencing algorithm that operates correctly when the polygon crosses the meridian and anti-meridian?  I have't found such a thing yet for Javascript / node and I have a python program that I need to migrate but can't due to the lack of a workable point in polygon method.

Comment: @RoyHB I'm using https://github.com/uber/in-n-out which is makes use of https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon.

I'm not sure if they solve thee meridian crossing problem or not.

Comment: There's a ton of ways to approach this and I think only experimentation and knowing your use case can lead you to the best way, but one suggestion you could try is to create a "boundary region" polygon by taking the original polygon and scaling it by a factor of `alpha` and shrinking it by a factor of `beta`, and creating the polygon that is like a ring around the boundary of the original polygon from these two. Then query for events in the ring and sort them by date and examine adjacent pairs for enter/exit events. Tuning `alpha` and `beta` could be tricky, depending on speed variations.

Comment: I am also in the same situation.. What did you do @jus101 ?? Could you please provide the answer if you solved it ?

Comment: @abhi191 I haven't actually had time to work on this problem. Our current solution (see the start of my question) allows users to select a maximum of 7 days to report on a location. This seems to be sufficient for our use case.

Comment: @jus101, I had a similar issue and tackled it using a location table and a trigger table. In order to minimize the amount of data I was working with, I only stored two points per user, the current point, and the previous point. Then I would use these two points to determine if a user had entered a fence, exited a fence, was still inside a fence, or still outside a fence. Then based on the fence and whether the user had entered, exited, or was dwelling, I would send a message. You could simply store a new record in a log table instead and report on the log.

https://github.com/bp4151/SSGeoAPI